# How do I get my nodejs project to transpile all of the javascript files?

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, babeljs, transpiler

I am attempting to figure out how to run the equivalent of babel-node in production. My current project structure is as follows:

```
top_level_of_my_application
    dist
       --index.js
    lib  
       --index.js  
    public  
       -->images
       -->...
    server  
       -->models
       -->routes
       -->...  
    .babelrc  
    app.js  
    package.json  
    node_modules
```

My "lib/index.js" file imports my "app.js" file before creating an express server using the following code:

```
import app     from '../app';
import http    from 'http';

// Get port from environment and store in Express.
let port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3001');
app.set('port', port);

// Create HTTP server.
let server = http.createServer(app);
```

My .babelrc file is as follows:

```
{
  "ignore": ["node_modules/**/*"],
  "presets": ["env"]
}
```

I have installed babel-cli, babel-core, babel-loader, and babel-preset-env attempted to run the following scripts:

```
"scripts": {
    "prebuild": "rm -rf dist/*",
    "build": "babel -d dist lib",
    "start": "node dist/index.js"
}
```

After running build, it produces the dist directory with index.js inside. However, when I try to run start, I get the following error:

---

import 'env-import';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token import"

---

The first few lines of my app.js file are:

```
"use strict";

// Load environment vars
import 'env-import';
import express      from 'express';
import path         from 'path';
```

Does anyone know how I can make sure that my app.js and subsequent files are transpiled properly so that I can run the application from node?

Comment: you probably need to configure babel (see http://www.pauleveritt.org/articles/pylyglot/es6_imports/) ; alternatively you can use node es6 modules experimentally in node(9+) if you feel courageous (https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html)

Comment: The first link you provided covers how to get mocha up and running, but does not use a package (it uses babel-core/register) that is viewed as good for production environments. Using the experimental modules, it seems that I would have to rename all of my javascript files to use the new "mjs" extension. There are more than 100 of them so if there another way I would much rather prefer to do that.